# powershell Script for moving specific files from a folder based on a filename.txt

Tags: powershell

I have a folder that contains 2000+ Jpeg images
I want to copy some images from this folder to another folder based on the filename that I have in sort.txt file.
I have a filename in text format. how this can be done?

Source is E:\SORT\RUSH
Destination is  E:\SORT\SORTED
filename list is E:\sort.txt

```
$file_list = Get-Content E:\sort.txt
foreach ($file in $file_list) {
    $subf = $file.Split('-')[0]    
    $source = "E:\SORT\RUSH"
    Copy-Item $source E:\SORT\SORTED -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: "filename in text format" doesn't mean much... Are each file name on a separate line? A single line of comma-separated values? something in between?

Comment: they are in
 376A8295
376A8296
376A8297

Comment: they are in different line

Comment: $file_list = Get-Content E:\sort.txt
foreach ($file in $file_list) {
    $subf = $file.Split('-')[0]    
    $source = "E:\SORT\RUSH"
    Copy-Item $source E:\SORT\SORTED -WhatIf
}

Comment: Please [edit your existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70999508/edit) and add the relevant details (including any code you've already written) :)

Comment: its done, can you help

Comment: What is in your E:\sort.txt file? Just the file names? Including `.jpg` extension?  Your code seems to split the filename on the hyphen, but the commented name exampled do not have that ???

Comment: no extension, i have copied the code from some other site, i am a new person to powershell correct me if am wrong

Comment: the list has only names no extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so now we know the input textfile only contains file BaseNames (no extension), you need to check if such a file can be found in the $source directory.

Try

```
$source      = 'E:\SORT\RUSH'
$destination = 'E:\SORT\SORTED'

# first, make sure the destination folder exists
$null = New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force

# make sure no duplicates are in the text file
$file_list = Get-Content -Path 'E:\sort.tx' | Select-Object -Unique
foreach ($file in $file_list) {
    # create the full path and filename for the file to copy
    $sourceFile = Join-Path -Path $source -ChildPath "$file.jpg"
    # if the file can be found, copy it
    if (Test-Path -Path $sourceFile -PathType Leaf) {
        Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $destination
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Could not find file '$sourceFile'"
    }
}
```